# For analog summing and multiplying, what would be the disadvantages of scaling down voltages of input?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, analog

let us say that we have an analog summer based on op-amps. For the reason related to maximum output voltage of op-amps, one wants to scale down the input voltages by constant factor.

Would this cause significant problems for sum? Would there be an internal problem other than noise problems? Would frequencies of an output signal be significantly biased toward some frequency range?

Comment: Opamps don't have threshold voltages. Internal noise problems ? Output frequencies biased toward a frequency range ?? What are you talking about ??? If you want to ask a question OK but some basic knowledge of amplifiers / opamps is required for this to become a meaningfull discussion.

Comment: Opamps have supply voltage, which serves as threshold voltage. But opamps need to be adjusted to "serve" supply voltage.

Comment: We don't call that a threshold voltage, we call that maximum output voltage range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular serious problem with this approach. The inputs don't need to stay within the supply voltage range if the series resistors are high enough (though you do need to worry about what may happen if the input is connected to an external voltage and there is no supply voltage- the summing junction will no longer be at virtual ground and current will flow *somewhere*).

You can calculate the voltage and current noise as usual, high value resistors will have greater Johnson-Nyquist noise, and the noise current of the amplifier will have more influence, but neither is normally much of an issue.

It may be necessary to add some capacitors in the resistor ratio if you have very high value resistors (to get flatter AC response, increase stability and decrease noise).